# Is there a simple way to delete all members from a role

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a user defined role called OrderEntry in my database that only has two members.  Dropping them individually to in turn drop the role isn't a big deal. However I can see this being an issue if the situation arose where you needed to drop a role and needed to delete all members from that role first.  Is there a simple way to do that for future reference.  I'm thinking in terms of SQL script

Comment: your question is confusing, you want to delete rows of that role? or you want to remove the kind of role for those users?

Comment: From what I understand about dropping a role you need to no long have members in that role.  The way to drop a member in my situation would be  ALTER ROLE OrderEntery DROP MEMBER JohnDoe.   Then once the member is dropped I can drop the role   DROP ROLE OrderEntery.    If there are multipe members in that role, and I want to delete them is there a simple way to delete all of them or do they all have to be deleted individually?

Comment: you want to delete members of the same role? am i right?

Comment: I believe that's what i'm asking

Comment: does DELETE FROM tableName WHERE ROLE OrderEntry doesn't work?

Comment: Not sure how that would delete a user from a role in my database

Comment: @JCBorlagdan - I believe they're talking about the *built in* roles functionality within SQL Server (e.g. they want to run [`DROP ROLE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms174988.aspx)). Not roles that they've modelled as entries in a table.

Comment: aaaah my bad thanks for clearing it out @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 'ALTER ROLE ' +  QUOTENAME(rp.name)  + ' DROP MEMBER ' + QUOTENAME(mp.name)
from sys.database_role_members drm
  join sys.database_principals rp on (drm.role_principal_id = rp.principal_id)
  join sys.database_principals mp on (drm.member_principal_id = mp.principal_id)
WHERE rp.name = 'OrderEntery '
order by rp.name
```

YOU COULD CREATE all the ALTER ROLE DROP MEMBER Syntax like this. Take the result query and run it.

The result should look like this

```
ALTER ROLE [OrderEntery ] DROP MEMBER [user1]
ALTER ROLE [OrderEntery ] DROP MEMBER [user2]
ALTER ROLE [OrderEntery ] DROP MEMBER [user3]
ALTER ROLE [OrderEntery ] DROP MEMBER [user4]
```

Edit :

From msdn:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189780.aspx
  sys.database_role_members - Returns one row for each member of each
  database role.
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187328.aspx
  sys.database_principals - Returns a row for each security principal
  in a SQL Server database.

Comment: That's a little over my head at the moment.  I'll take some time to puzzle it out

Comment: It's not that complicated, basically with the query, you get all the users from a specific role ( using the where clause). Then you add the text to create an `alter role ... drop member ...` syntax so you get ALTER DROP for each members of the role you want.

Comment: Sure...I just don't know what the sys.database_role_members stuff comes from....i'm newbie

Comment: They are the SQL Server tables, where sql stores his datas. You would expect that SQL Server to store all his data in tables, these are the tables used for members and roles.

Comment: @secretTina take a look at the edits. Hope it helps.